# When explicitly setting the date formatter, it breaks when in french?

Tags: c#, datetime

When a user is viewing the content in french I set the culture like:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-CA");
```

And when in english I set it as:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-CA");
```

Now dates are stored in en-CA format so I explicity always format using:

```
var dateFormatPattern = "M/d/yyyy"; // "MM/dd/yyyy"

var dt = DateTime.MinValue;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, dateFormatPattern, null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dtResult))
{
    dt = dtResult;
}
```

Now it works in english, but when in french mode, the parse fails.

When in debug mode, I can see the value of dateString is the same in both french and english, but could it be the IDE changing the format?  Since it is a string value, I don't think it could.

Then why is it failing?

Comment: It would be much easier to understand if you show values that fail/work fr each language...

Comment: The date string value is the same in both cases: "02/13/2013"

Comment: I just tried your example and the date string is parsed correctly with either CultureInfo, only the output differs.

Answer (score 2):

The date separator for the french culture is the dash. When you pass a format string to `TryParseExact`, any slashes in the format string must be matched by whatever the date separator is in the input date.

This means that when parsing with the format `M/d/yyyy` and the french culture, you need to supply a string with the format `M-d-yyyy` for the parse to succeed. The english culture's date separator is the slash, so you don't see any problem there.

The correct fix depends on where the input comes from and how lenient you want to be (e.g. what if a user is viewing french content but supplies a date formatted with slashes?).

Comment: Does Convert.ToDateTime use the current culture?  what about DateTime.TryParse?   What is strange is I am explicitly setting the format when using DateTime.TryParseExact and it still fails!

Comment: @user1361315: The documentation on MSDN covers all of that. As for the format, realize that `/` in the format string does **not** mean a `/` is expected in the input. Rather, it means that *whatever character is the date separator for the culture in effect* is expected in the input. If you always want to match a slash, use `'/'` (slash between single quotes) in the format string.